# input title overlapping loading div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a input title overlapping a loading div and I don´t know how to solve this bug.

The input:
[image]

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
    <table id="clientesGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    <div id="clientesPager">
    </div>
<p></p>

     $('#clientesGrid').jqGrid({
           //...
      }).navGrid('#clientesPager', { view: false, del: false, add: false, edit: false, search: false },
           { width: 400 }, // default settings for edit
           {}, // default settings for add
           {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
           { multipleSearch: true }, // search options
           {} /* view parameters*/
         ).navButtonAdd('#clientesPager', {
             id: "addClienteJuridicoButton",
             caption: paramFromViewClientes.AddClienteJuridicoText,
             title: paramFromViewClientes.AddClienteJuridicoText,
             buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
             onClickButton: function () {
                 addClienteToExpedienteForm($("#idSolicitudHidden").val(), 2);
             },
             position: "first"
         })
        .navButtonAdd('#clientesPager', {
            id: "addClienteFisicoButton",
            caption: paramFromViewClientes.AddClienteFisicoText,
            title: paramFromViewClientes.AddClienteFisicoText,
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
            onClickButton: function () {
                addClienteToExpedienteForm($("#idSolicitudHidden").val(), 1);
            },
            position: "first"
        });
```

So as you can see its a jqgrid with 2 buttons to add new customers and in these 2 buttons I got the bug with the loading div.

Loading div bug:

[image]

Loading div css:

```
.divModalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*! important !*/
    display: none; /* last attribute set darkness on scale: 0...1.0 */
    /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);*/
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    /*FOR IE*/
    background-color: black;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
}
```

Comment: share your full code

Comment: `-ms-filter` F'YEAH

Comment: Setting the correct values of the z-index of the <div> and the tooltip elements is the way to go